# SQl Query to Hibernate Query

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, jdbc, groovy

I have a MySQL query that I use to retrieve random rows from a table. The query is:

```
SELECT * FROM QUESTION WHERE TESTID=1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;
```

Now I need to change this query to ***Hibernate***. Did a bit of googling but couldn't find the answer. Can someone provide help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [post](http://cephas.net/blog/2004/05/21/hibernate-returning-n-records-in-a-random-order/), you can do that :

```
String query = "from QUESTION order by newid()";
Query q = session.createQuery(query);
q.setMaxResults(10);
```

Not sure if it will work (especially for the random part), but you can try it :)

Answer (score 2):

The random function is different between each underlying DB and is not a standard part of SQL92.

Given that you will need to implement a SQLDialect for the given database type you are using.

eg:

```
class PostgresSQLDialect extends org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect {
    PostgresSQLDialect() {
        super()
        registerFunction( "rand", new NoArgSQLFunction("random", Hibernate.DOUBLE) );
    }
}
```

Then you will need to define that dialect in the config

```
hibernate {
    dialect='com.mycompany.sql.PostgresSQLDialect'
}
```